# Best approach to bind a datagridview to database entity/ies

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

Is this aproach the best that exist to databind a datagridview?

I've seen many people with problems binding datagridviews and after a lot of work I found this as the best method. I hope it helps other people, and someone can add an improvement.

**Step 1) Create the dataGridView and its columns with the editor.**

**Step 2) Create an object that represents a row in the datagridview.**

This object may have as many instances of database entities as you need. Here's an example with two objects (two columns in the datagridview)

```
public class ObjectToShow
{
    MyDatabaseObject myDatabaseObject = new MyDatabaseObject();

    public ObjectToShow(MyDatabaseObject myDatabaseObject)
    {
        this.myDatabaseObject = myDatabaseObject;
    }

    public string Data1 //to asign to a datagridview column
    {
        get { return myDatabaseObject.data1; }
        set { myDatabaseObject.data1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Data1")}
    }

    public string Data2 //to asign to another datagridview column
    {
        get { return myDatabaseObject.data2; }
        set { myDatabaseObject.data2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Data2"); }
    }

    //This is to notify the changes made to the object directly and not from the control. This refreshes the datagridview.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

**Step 3) In the Form create a BindingList of ObjectToshow and a bindingSource as follow**

```
BindingList<ObjectToshow> ObjectToShow_list = new BindingList<ObjectToshow>();
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
```

**Step 4) Create the bindings this way**

```
//if we don't put this, each public property in ObjectToshow will generate a new column in the datagridview
//I think it's best to create the columns from the editor.
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

//database -> <- bindingList -> <- bindingSource -> <- datagridview <- user
bindingSource.DataSource = ObjectToShow_list;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;

dataGridView1.Columns["Column_Data1"].DataPropertyName = "Data1";
dataGridView1.Columns["Column_Data2"].DataPropertyName = "Data2";
```

**Step 5) query the database**

```
//Example bringing all the data from a database table. This should be done in a controller class.
My_DBModel DB_context = new My_DBModel();    
List<myDatabaseObject> myDatabaseObject_list = DB_context.myDatabaseObject.ToList();

//Clear de previous data    
ObjectToShow_list.Clear();

//Add the queried elements to the bindingList
foreach (myDatabaseObject item in myDatabaseObject_list)
{
    ObjectToshow objectToshow = new ObjectToshow(item);
    ObjectToShow_list.Add(objectToshow);
}
```

**Step 6) Modify the data from the bindingList or the datagridview as you want. Then DB_context.saveChanges().**

To add data, add it directly to DB_context.myDatabaseObject.Add(new ...) and query the database again; If you want to add it from the datagridview I think you have to handle the event and add it to the context anyway.

This is what I do and it works, but I'm not sure if it's the best way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Step 5)` is pretty unclear to me. One of the main advantages of your approach is decouple the Database Model from the business model. You do that by creating a class that can hold properties from several tables. But then you query only one table. The reason I'm writing this is that when you want to get data from several tables but put it in one object you would want to do as much work as possible on the Database Server side so when your query is executed it fetches the data so that you can directly populate the object properties.

Comment: @Leron Please tell me specifically what is unclear from step 5. maybe I can update it to help you.

Comment: del Rio I'm just sharing thoughts, I don't need help on something in particular. As said above - I don't see the benefit from making all this effort if at the end you'll query only one table and if you don't, it's much more important how you'll build your expression tree so that the hard work is done in the database. Also - in MVC design to have something like this - `My_DBModel DB_context = new My_DBModel(); ` in the controller is not what you want. What I think is better is another project to take care for your data access.

Comment: @Leron can you put or link some example?

Comment: I'll try to put my thoughts together later. For now I just want to make it clear that I'm not saying that your approach will not work, or will cause problems I just think there are things that could be done better. If you are interested in what I'm talking about take a look at `Repository` pattern, `Unit Of Work` pattern, some Dependency container like `Unity` or `NInject`, and also you might also want to research why using the `DbContext` directly from the controller is not the best approach in MVC pattern.

Answer (score 3):

So, in order to explain my thoughts better I'll write an answer (as it doesn't restrict me with the character count) but I 
want to make it clear that I only add my thoughts about how your initial code could be made better and not how it must be
done.
Having said that let's get into the topic. I'll start with `Step 2) Create an object that represents a row in the datagridview.`
because I think this is what it's all about. Your database model (the tables and the columns for each table) sometime will reflect
your business model, but sometimes in your business logic you'll need to use information from 2 or more database tables and I think
that the most common approach is the one you've chosen - create a new class that represents the business logic needs. Even here you 
are given some options like using anonymous objects or `[NotMapped]` properties but I'll leave these to someone that actually prefers 
any of these other options since I also would go with a new class.
I'll skip step 3 and 4 since I don't think I have something of value to write about that and go straight to `Step 5) query the database`.
The first thing that I think should be reconsider is the responsibilities that you give to each `Model`, `View` and `Controller`. As I wrote
in one of my comments, in my opinion having another project dedicated to handle the data access is as far the best approach I've found. Why I
prefer this approach? Well - first, as I wrote, your database model will most probably not reflect your business model. Let say in your project you
have `Model` folder and you put there all the entities plus the business objects. It's confusing, even with a fairly small application you will find 
yourself with many classes and it will be difficult even for you at some point to tell which class represents a database tables (entity) and which you
use in your business logic. It will be even harder for the man after you to find out those things, or even you, after a few months later. So it's a simple
thing that can make your code much more readable which alone is not a small achievement. And after some more reading about how to decouple an application 
if we decide that indeed a separate project for data access is a good approach, then it makes a lot of sense to put the logic for getting that data in this project.
The way I like to do that (keep in mind I don't have much experience, I'm learning as I'm writing this stuff) is to use `Repository` pattern. You can read a lot
about this pattern and the different ways it's used, but just to show you the advantage of using repository instead of

```
My_DBModel DB_context = new My_DBModel();    
List<myDatabaseObject> myDatabaseObject_list = DB_context.myDatabaseObject.ToList();
```

Let's say you have two entities - `User` and `Order`. And you have a `GenericRepository` that implements the basic methods that you will use while manipulating data:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal MyDbContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(MyDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return dbSet;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(long id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }
    //And so on...
```

and you have also `UserRepository` and `OrderRepository` which both inherit from the `GenericRepository` so already for each entity you have all basic methods 
        implemented so you don't have to repeat yourself every time when you want to perform `Delete` or `Update`.And why I don't like `My_DBModel DB_context = new My_DBModel();`?
        Well, imagine that you use some method, let's say `GetOrdersBySomething()` and you use this method on several places in your code by querying the database. What will happen if
        someone decides to write a stored procedure which will return this information from now on - you have to find all places where you actually use this method and change the logic.
        Let's say that few months later you have to use data from a web service too.. each change force you to rewrite the same logic on different places in your application. But if you
        use repository you will just have `GetOrdersBySomething()` in your `OrdersRepository` and each time when you have to make a change you gonna make it only here and nowhere else.

Also, if I understood your post correctly, the main topic is about being able to collect data from several tables in the database and bind it as a datasource. So what kind of problems
        this may cause. Even if you are dealing with relatively small amount of data, if you first query each table separately and then try to populate your business object on the server side this 
        may cause a big performance issue. If you have to use let say 3 tables each with 10columns, that makes 30 columns total. If you need only 15 of them, then what you want is the database server to 
        do it's work and return those columns in the way you need them, so the work on the server side is as little as possible. Which lead me to the next topic that I point out - the expression trees. I won't
        write much about them cause I don't think I have some deep understanding about them, but here is the official msdn page about the topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx where you
        can read more about what expression tree is, what is the idea behind it. And when you get the idea of what exactly expression tree is, then it will be more clear why I think that your example where
        you query against only one table is not the best one, because this approach really shines when you execute the appropriate query.

Comment: Thanks for introduce many people to your aproach. I'm gonna have it in mind, it's very usefull.

Answer (score 1):

You could just bind the `DataGridView` to the `DataSource` with AutoGenerateColumns on something like

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = [yourDataSource]
```

Then loop through the columns and set their properties in the loop which would allow you to hide columns you don't want to see, name headers etc.

This is how I do mine

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvReconciledItems.Columns)
{
    switch (col.Name)
    {
        case "Column1":
            col.HeaderText = "Header1";
            col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            col.FillWeight = 30;
            break;
        case "Column2":
            col.HeaderText = "Header2";
            col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            col.FillWeight = 10;
            break;

        default:
            col.Visible = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Any questions let me know

Comment: Yeah, it works, but what if you want to mix two entities in one datagrid? In my case I just have to add the instance (of the other entity) in the ObjectToShow and add the corresponding public attribute. You can make use of the get methods to show something else or in another format too.

Comment: Create your objectToShow then populate it with the values from both entities adding each created objecttoshow to a list. Then bind the datagridview to the list and loop through the columns to format appropriatly

Comment: Thanks for comment guys. That is my aproach too, creating the object. You just configure the columns by code. I like to do it from the editor so you can see the changes in code time.